# Angular and Rxjs: getting not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>' error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following function in an angular component.

```
getPreviewFilterColumns(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.userFiltersBehaviorSubject.asObservable()
               .pipe(
                   map(filters => this.flattenFilterColumns([], filters.rules))
               );
}
```

When building the project I get the following error.

> src/app/services/row-filter.service.ts(248,24): error TS2684: The
>   'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of
>   type 'Observable<{}>'.

Line 248 is the line with the map() function.

The types and declarations of the variables and functions being used are as follows.

```
private userFiltersBehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<FilterGroup>(_.cloneDeep(DEFAULT_FILTER_GROUP));

private flattenFilterColumns(array: string[], rules: any): string[] {
    for (const rule of rules) {
        if (_.has(rule, 'rules')) {
            this.flattenFilterColumns(array, rule);
        } else {
            array.push(rule.field);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

My package.json file shows I am using the following.

```
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
"@angular/common": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "5.0.0",
```

I'm really banging my head against the wall trying to track this bug down. It looks like it should work to me. What am I missing?

Comment: It could be that TypeScript cannot figure out the type of `filters` in your `map` function. Try specifying the type for `filters` value.

Comment: Your dependencies are out of date and frankly a bunch of this has changed and recent versions of the language and Frameworks

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar issue